# Creating cmake install macro for a library

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

This my project structure:

```
main
|
--src
   |
   --feed.h
   --feed.cc
   --other files
   --CMakeLists2.txt
--test
   |
   --test.cpp
   --CMakeLists3.txt
CMakeLists1.txt
```

CMakeLists1.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)
project (Feedparser)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH cmake)

find_package(PTHREAD REQUIRED)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++14" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14 ")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x ")
else()
        message(STATUS "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()

add_subdirectory (src)

add_subdirectory (test)
```

CMakeLists2.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)

add_library (Feedparser news.h xml2json.hpp jsonxx.cc curler.cc feed.cc )

target_link_libraries(Feedparser pthread)
target_link_libraries(Feedparser curl)

install(TARGETS Feedparser
        RUNTIME DESTINATION bin
        LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION /usr/lib)
install(FILES "feed.h" DESTINATION /usr/include  )
target_include_directories (Feedparser PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

CMakeLists3.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8.11)

add_executable(Feedtest test.cc)

target_link_libraries (Feedtest LINK_PUBLIC Feedparser)
```

Here is my Header file.

feed.h

```
#include "news.h"
#include "curler.cc"
#include "jsonxx.h"
#include "jsonxx.cc"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace jsonxx;

class feed{

    map <string,string> info;
    std::map<int, Object> items;
    string url;
    news News;
    Object *item;
    void strip_items();
    public:
        Object json;

        feed(string url);

        void create(string url){
            this->url = url;
        }
        feed(){}
        string get_topic(){
            return info["title"];
        }
        bool fetch();
        bool fetch_data();
        bool parse();
        string get_url(){
            return url;
        }
        string get_item_title(int index){
            return News.title[index];
        }

        string get_item_img(int index){
            return News.image[index];
        }

        string get_item_link(int index){
            return News.link[index];
        }

        int get_total(){
            return News.num_item;
        }

        struct news get_news(){
            return News;
        }



};
```

Should I include feed.h in feed.cc and compile and how does the compiler directly link .h files with the .cxx files in archives?

How do i write a cmake script for installing this library? 
Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

C++'s building process consists of 2 stages:

**Compilation**: The compiler runs on every source (`.cc`) file, generating an intermidiate binary.

**Linking**: The linker runs on every intermidiate binary, matching declarations with definitions.
Finally, it combines all of them to make the final binary.

---

With this in mind, you need to make sure the compiler doesn't come across something that it doesn't know about. That's why you include headers (`.h`).

The linker should be fed with everything the compiler creates.

Comment: Is the same case for archives? and should i include the .h files i the .cc files? or do i compile them externally? What changes must be done to the cmake files for moving the .h and .a files to /usr/include and /usr/lib/ respectively? @IvanRubinson